# highcharts pointRange in tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, tooltip, column-chart

I want to take the pointRange value of highCharts data on the tooltip for column Chart.

This is how my data looks...

```
series: [{
                    name:'Segment1',
                    type: 'column',
                    data: [{"x":0,"y":12000}],
                    color: '#8B0000',
                    pointRange: 8

                },
                    {  
                        name:'Segment2',
                        type: 'column',
                        data: [{"x":10,"y":11000}],
                        color: '#FFA500',
                        pointRange: 12
                    },...
```

This is the tooltip formatting I am doing...

```
tooltip: {
formatter: function () {
return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>'+ '<br>' + 'Height' + ': ' + this.y
+ '<br>'+ 'Width ' + this.series.pointRange; },
```

But the value by using this.series.pointRange is coming as 'undifined' in the tooltip.

Comment: Try to access it via this.series.options.pointRange

Comment: @morganfree yes it worked. thnx